# Which is the best way to show url link images into android view

Tags: android

I have the image URL in JSON response now I want URL to load its image into desired ImageView in my android application. What I have to use for this?? I mean which is the best way??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Please post some code. and to retrieve your image into image view you can use picasso library to directly get image into imageview from String url.

add picasso first,

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

use below code to load image,

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

there are many more methods available in this library.

go through this link : [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation of `Glide.`

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library

You can use this library for `image`

Just Add dependencies in `App Module`

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0'
```

Add below in root gradle

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}
```

and use below code

```
 GlideApp
    .with(yourContext)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop() //optional
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner) //optional
    .into(myImageView);
```